# adding a close icon to a modal pop, anchored to specific location

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a modal pop being triggered in a website that's pretty simple, all white solid color background (not image). The css styling is as follows:

```
<style>
        #element_to_pop_up 
        {
             display:none;
             background-color:#ffffff;
             width:500px;
             height:250px;
             padding-left:20px;
             padding-right:20px;
             padding-top:20px;  
        }
    </style>
```

To close the modal you can click anywhere outside the modal confines.

I have a simple "x" icon transparent png that I want to hover over this area to the upper right. It doesnt need any special coding, since clicking on it is technically clicking outside the confines of the modal, which closes it anyway.

How can I add this png to always be locked to the upper right corner of the modal but sits outside the main class since I want it to be treated like the "outside" or close-trigger area of the page?

Comment: Set absolute positioning and put it inside some element with relative positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this HTML:

```
<div id="element_to_pop_up">
    <span>X</span> // This part can be your image
</div>
```

You can use absolute positioning to put it where you want:

```
#element_to_pop_up {
    background-color:#000;
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    margin: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

#element_to_pop_up span {
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    top: -15px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b3a10w0w/

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Comment: This (basically) works.. I do have one added question, and this just shows my relative suckiness at css. There are two divs below it that have content that display a message, that are positioned correctly without the "X". The second I add the "X" as above, it "pulls" them up. Example:   <span><img src="images/x.png" /></span>
            <div style="font-size:25px; font-weight:bold; font-style: italic; color:#4d90fe;"></div>

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in my fiddle and post the link here? It'll be easier to understand. :)

Comment: When I add my divs to your fiddle, it works properly. Let me mess with it for a minute and see if theres some other css interfering with it. There are .net labels in the divs that might be carrying some inherent formatting im not considering.

Comment: No problem. In case you will be able to reproduce the problem, just let me know. In other case, if this solution solves your problem, remember to accept it as answer. :)